# Item is getting enlarged during drag in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an sample code below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a class='dragitem' href='#' draggable='true'><img src="myimage.gif" width=12px height=12px border=0px padding="0px 0px 0px 0px" align=left>Drag Me</a>"
  </body>
</html>
```

above  item is getting enlarged in Firefox while dragging the item & in other browsers (IE & Chrome) it is not getting enlarged. If i remove  tag inside  it is working as expected in all browsers (item isn't getting enlarged).  I have attached the images while dragging.

please let me know, How can I stop this item getting enlarged in Firefox while dragging ?

[image: In Chrome & IE]

[image: In Firefox]

Comment: Please also share your css code. The problem may be there.

Comment: Share your entire code

Comment: @NaeemUlWahhab there no separate CSS for this, all I have written inside <a> & <img> tags only & above is the whole code I have. you can observe this behavior by running above code in Firefox.

Comment: @RohitVerma all I have is above code only.

Comment: Add a working snippet. I mean, use the snippet editor or jsfiddle (preferably the snippet editor), so we can play around without losing time instead of copying and pasting your code in our fiddle. Is a good practice. That way you will receive more help.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález did the change, thanks.

Comment: I'm having this issue on anything I drag in firefox.  I tried a different display and it seems dependent on the devicePixelRatio in my case so I think it s a firefox feature.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to know that **links and images are draggable by default** according to [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_draggable.asp). You don't need to put the property `draggable="true"` for your link. About Firefox behavior, I try your code and discover that it's because of the image inside your link that your drag effect enlarged the size of the content. With this code, you don't have it (I put the image outside of the link) :

```
<body>
  <a class='dragitem' href='#'>Drag Me</a>
  <img src="myimage1.gif" width=12px height=12px border=0px padding="0px 0px 
  0px 0px" align=left>
</body>
```

You can try and you will there is no more the enlarged effect on Firefox. Now the question is what is the purpose of your image ? Why to put on a link HTML structure ? I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the replay, I am working on legacy code where  I have seen this behavior so made a sample application & tried, its showing a same behavior in Firefox. above code may not work in my case as I have to show image also getting dragged in my application, in your code image is not getting dragged along with item.

Comment: one more thing, i have to show <image item image> , <image image item>, <item image image> and other combinations also.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a Firefox bug or feature. If you use a larger drag object it won't resize it up but if it's too small it assumes you need it larger to see it or something like that. Since you'll have to use js/jquery for the logic why not use [jQuery UI's draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) instead? you'll have more control over the drag and styling.

```js
$(".dragitem").draggable({
    addClasses: false,
    revert: true
});
```

```css
.ui-draggable-dragging a{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<a class="dragitem" style="position:absolute" href='#' ><img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" width=22px height=18px border=0px padding="0px 0px 0px 0px" align=left />Drag Me</a>
```